# Addthis social share does not show share count

Tags: addthis

I've got a problem with share counting.

It works fine on the index page but on other pages Addthis does not show the share count number.

I use this script in main js then other page extends this script

```html
<!-- Base.html.twig file start -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></script>
<!-- Base.html.twig file end -->


<!-- Index.html.twig page start -->
    {% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

    <body>
      <h1>Index page share count work fine</h1>
    </body>  
<!-- Index.html.twig page end -->


<!-- About-us.html.twig page start -->
    {% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

    <body>
      <h1>About us page share count it's not working</h1>
    </body>  
<!-- About-us.html.twig page end -->
```

**File structure**

**about-us**

- index.html.twig

**common**

- extra-script.html.twig

base.html.twig

index.html.twig

[image]

[image]
**index.html.twig**

[image]
**about-us.html.twig**

Share function is working fine but only the share count is not working on pages other than the index page.

Would anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Post your code so that we can have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Ok wait a minute.

Comment: try this and follow the instruction http://platform.sharethis.com/get-inline-share-buttons#

Comment: what is your file structure?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Sorry i'm a beginner.

I already post my new structure It a symfony framework 
Base on twig template

Comment: That's alright. What I'm asking is, how does your code directory look like? The problem could be that since the second `html` file is located in another folder, it is unable to load the required file containing the **count** code.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight that is my file structure

Comment: looks like it *is* because of the file structure. Have a look at how files in different directories should be loaded/ linked. Cheers

Comment: @TheDarkKnight I've already checked file directory. I think it works fine. I've  already update my directory in my post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147340/discussion-between-b-godoak-and-thedarkknight).